# php and ajax - upload base64 photo and return link to edit

Tags: php, ajax, permissions, http-status-code-401, photo-upload

I've tried to make this:

- Upload photo from a PC as base64 string ("data:image/jpeg;base64,...")
- PHP will save this photo in full resolition as .jpg and make 160x160 .png thumbnail
- Then it will return link to full-size image and user will crop this photo using [Jcop](http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop.html) and send dimensions automaticly when user confirm

I've done this pretty far and it works fine on my local Apache. But when I've moved it to remote web-hosting **(I dont have access to shell)** the first ajax request (when user submit the photo) returns **401 Unauthorized**. I searched for wrong files permissions but I'm not sure if it's problem of **photo.php's permissions** or the **uploaded image's permissions**. I've set **0650** to all directories.

Captured request: http://netbox.wayo.cz/401unauthorized.PNG

Here is code that saves the photo:

```
if($image = imagecreatefromstring($content))
{
     // save full-size photo
     if($photo = imagejpeg($image,$file_path,$control->get_config('upload_photo_quality')))
     {  
        // get photo params
        list($width,$height,$type,$attr) = getimagesize($file_path);

        // create photo thumbnail
        $thumb_name = uniqid().'.png';
        $thumb_path = DIR_DATA.'thumbs/'.$thumb_name;
        imagepng($image,$thumb_path,$control->get_config('upload_photo_compression'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must Set **654**, in **650** public user can not access the directory and inner File if You Request For PHP Must Set **655** that allow user to Execute PHP file

Comment: I tried to change permissons of those foldes but it says: 
`Command: SITE CHMOD 654/www/domains/netbox.wayo.cz/app/ajax/edit`
`Response: 550 SITE CHMOD command failed.`

Comment: become sure last directory permission is set 655 for example first set  **/ajax/** permission  then set **/edit/**  permission  I recommended use FTP program like **cuteftp** for set permission

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I'm still having that problem with permissions, but I'm discussing it with my hosting provider and it seems that my root FTP account doesn't have required permissions to change it. But it's fault of the provider because other FTP accounts my friends have are able to change those permissions.